# How do I prevent images in HTML signature from wrapping on iphone & Android?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, wordpress

I need to finalize a company email signature.  It looks great on the desktop, but when it is opened on an iPhone or Android, the images wrap onto the next line.  They should all be on the same line to create the full effect. See code below.

```
<span style="color: #000000;"><em><span style="color: #808080;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-250" src="https://mtgrecruiter.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/kelley-lobona-051-e1473885068625.jpg" alt="kelley-lobona-05" width="392" height="100" /><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-251" src="https://mtgrecruiter.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/kelley-lobona-061-e1473885082990.jpg" alt="kelley-lobona-06" width="53" height="100" /><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-252" src="https://mtgrecruiter.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/kelley-lobona-071-e1473885094151.jpg" alt="kelley-lobona-07" width="48" height="100" /></span></em></span><br />
<em><span style="color: #808080;">p</span></em>: <span style="color: #000000;">713-572-2100 |</span><em><span style="color: #808080;"> c:</span></em> <span style="color: #000000;">770-891-6968 |<span style="color: #808080;"><em> w: </em></span>www.proalt.com</span>
```

Comment: you have 3 images. the browser is free to split them however it thinks it should to make the page fit. If you want it non-splittable, why not make them one SINGLE image? And note that you're using external urls. those are unlikely to load in ANY mail client, unless the user explicitly allows external resources to be loaded.

Comment: Hi Mark, I should have explained... I need all 3 of those images to be "clickable" buttons - routing the recipient to a customer satisfaction survey.  But thank you for the heads up about the URL's.  Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: simple trick: single image with HTML [area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area)+map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That effect is happening because the outter `span` is not big enough to hold the images. So, you can set the `min-width` to de span, in order to get it as big as your three images. Furthermore, you should set de `display` property to `block`, since you can't fix the width for inline elements.

I advice you to use a `div` instead of that `span`. Anyway, here you have a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/xe3obc49/1/).

The trick is adding this to your span:

```
min-width:495px;
display:block;
```